# Cakephp with basic Auth Component

Tags: php, cakephp

I try use cakephp with auth component and it's not work.
Somebody can help me, Thank a lot.
this my code:

Controller file here

```
Class UsersController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Users';
var $uses = array('User');
var $viewPath = 'my_view/user';
var $layout = 'default';
var $helpers = array('javascript');

function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}

function login() {
    $this->layout = 'login';
}

function logout() {
    $this->layout = 'login';
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Model File:

```
Class User extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'User';
    var $useTable = 'users';
    var $belongsTo = array();
    var $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Username cannot empty'
        )
    );

}
```

AppController File:

```
var $components = array('Auth','Session');

function beforeFilter() {
    Security::setHash("md5");
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    //$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';
    $this->Auth->loginError = 'Invalid e-mail / password combination.  Please try again';
    $this->Auth->authError = "This  error shows up with the user tries to access a part of the website that is protected.";
}
```

In my view:

```
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
```

from my code, I need it to login to redirect to some page(example: dashboards/index).
And from this code must echo String from $this->Auth->loginError when login fail but it not show then I don't know to solve that. And in my db I store password by md5 too.
Code above I copy and try from Google
Thank again.

Comment: you haven't included auth component in your controller ->  `var $components  = array('Auth');`

Comment: Simply saying "its not working", is going to essentially ruin your chance of getting any in depth answer to your question. How about you try explain what is going on, what's it doing and what you're expecting it to do

Comment: @Rikesh Shah he has the component set in his appController so it is not needed in the controller.

Comment: Where is it failing? Can you get to the login page? can you login and not redirect? can you not login? There is no question here...

Comment: i can render login page but cannot login (cannot get session auth)..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, but if you followed the "simple authentication and authorization" tutorial on the site, you'll have to modify your "routes.php" to also allow access to "display" to get to your /pages/ controller. I have no idea if this is what your problem is, but it kind of seems like it.

Answer (score 0):

Well please put this statement ***$this->Auth->allow('login');*** in your users controllers beforeFilter() callback after the parent::beforeFilter();  call this would allow you to use the login action either you are logged in or not

Comment: send your email i will send you an application not full functional but you can get the idea of auth and ajax component;